# Is it possible that Office word content convert to Rich Text Field and keep format?

Tags: richtextarea

My customer usually copy n paste to rich text field from office word document, but the format always lost, is it possible that Office word content convert to Rich Text Field and keep format ?

Answer (score 2):

It should preserve all formatting if you use any browser apart from IE9. See [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SNMyAAO) for more details. This was fixed in Summer 13.

Comment: I am not sure that it's about brwowser, but I found another way to keep format.

Answer (score 1):

I found another to keep date format into rich text from MS word document, if I save as html file type(.htm), reopen this in chrome and copy n paste, it can keep table and indent safe in rich text field, awesome.

**1. Original Word document.**
[image: word]
**2. copy n paste to rich text field directly.**
[image]
**3. Save as Html File Type, reopen via Chrome and copy n paste.**
[image]